# I would like to use a multiplayer map in singleplayer. I downloaded it and followed many online guides, but the world never appears in singleplayer

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, aternos

Some time ago, I downloaded a world from Aternos, but I can't open it in singleplayer despite the use of many online guides.

Here is a screenshot of the folders I've got from Aternos:
[image]

Let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: Where are those folders located? Do you also have the world files, like `level.dat`, in the same location? For Minecraft to detect a world there needs to be a valid `level.dat` in a subfolder of the `saves` folder.